# Combine a column with a text in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, char

In a database product_description I have an some empty values for a column named custom_title (vchar). 
I'd like to update it with the values (vchar) from another one named "name" and a text.
I tried and return 0:

```
SELECT name + 'text' AS custom_title 
FROM product_description 
where custom_title is NULL
```

Comment: To concatenate strings in MySQL, use the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function: `SELECT CONCAT(name, 'text') AS custom_title ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT concat(name ,'text' ) AS custom_title FROM product_description where custom_title is NULL
```

if you want to update you need to use an update statement, not a select...

```
update product_description 
  set custom_title = concat(name ,'text' ) 
    where custom_title is NULL
```

---

To do the uppercase of the fist letter...

```
SELECT concat(upper(substring(name, 0,1 )),substring(name, 2) ,'text' ) AS custom_title 
    FROM product_description where custom_title is NULL
```

Comment: The custom title was empty not null, i've modified it to: where custom_title=''. But it shows the results, but doesn't save them. The custom_title colomn remains emty.

Comment: I have another question if possible please. In a colomn with a string I'd like to have the first letter of every word in capital letter

Comment: you need to do a string split, then convert the fist half to uppercase and then joint everything again.